# Software that shows space travel accurately in 3d from a physics point of view

Tags: science-based, space-travel, software-recommendations

An answer to the following question mentions a free online calculator for long-distance space travel.

[Software to ease my interstellar travel calculations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33757/software-to-ease-my-interstellar-travel-calculations)

I'm looking for a 3d simulator that accurately and visually shows transition from orbit and other aspects of interplanetary  (rather than interstellar) travel.

I don't care about trading between planets or social interactions or wars - just the travel aspect.

I'm thinking of purchasing Kerbal Space Program, https://www.kerbalspaceprogram.com/en/ which although it has cartoon green aliens as an extra,  does, I've heard, have accurate physics.

Does anyone have experience of this software?  Will it serve my purpose?

Does anyone have other recommendations?

**Requirements**

I'm hoping for software that shows heavenly bodies and spacecraft *visually* and in 3d from variable points of view, preferably with a zoom facility. The graphics don't have to be ultra-high-definition, just easy to recognise. I want to take account of amounts of thrust/fuel needed with realistic rocket equations built into the software (so I don't have to do them!) and to be able to travel from orbit around the home planet to orbit around the destination with course corrections where necessary. Takeoff from the planetary surface would be a bonus but not vital.

Worldbuilding - I want to build a fictional solar system with fictional planets but that has exploration and so on with realistic physics.Therefore the ability to place fictional planets around a fictional sun is highly desirable.

NOTE:  There is a tag especially for software-recommendations so I don't believe this question should be closed as 'opinion based'.

*There has been some difference of opinion about whether to use 'hard-science' or 'science-based'. I've finally settled on the latter. I don't want rocket equations in the answers, I just want the software to be as true to real physics as reasonably possible on your average Windows 10 machine.*

EDIT: I suppose I was hoping for something where I would say, "I'm in orbit on planet X and I'd like to be in orbit on planet Y - Please show me what fuel I need to carry, how long it will take me and the optimum trajectory". Judging by the answer by PSquall, I guess that's a very big ask. If that's not available then the nearest approximation will do nicely.

Comment: "does, I've heard, have accurate physics." - accurate enough for most purposes, but it does not perform full N-body simulation. Instead, it uses [Sphere of influence](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Sphere_of_influence) model. Difference in results is small, but it is there.

Comment: You might want to put your *pruposes* into en enumerated and possibly weighted list of *requirements*. makes this easier to answer

Comment: @dot_Sp0T  - Done

Comment: Software recommendations have previously, at least, been considered on topic *if there is a clear connection to worldbuilding*. This seems to me to qualify.

Comment: @a CVn - I think so too. Building a science-based universe for fictional characters to live in needs some way for them to realistically travel around and carry out their fictional trade, wars, explorations etc. There could potentially be hundreds of individual questions on this site (and there probably are) that would answer only one of the questions solved by this kind of software.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1356/)

Comment: Came here to post the above xkcd and say it is well worth it to get a feel for how the various maneuvers work.  as noted elsewhere, the physics are not quite accurate, but they are close and "good enough" for most purposes.

Comment: "in orbit on planet X and I'd like to be in orbit on planet Y - Please show me what fuel I need to carry, how long it will take me and the optimum trajectory" with "realistic rocket equations built into the software (so I don't have to do them!)" get **Kerbal Engineer Redux** and **MechJeb**. Those make your job in KPS just building rockets or spaceplanes, which you can fly manually if you *want* to.

Comment: In case no one has mentioned it: KSP is the hardest game I've ever played and has **a learning curve of *at least* several hundred hours**. KSP and the mods available *could* "serve your purpose"... eventually.

Answer (score 27):

Kerbal Space Program is an homage to the developments in the Space Race of the Cold War. You will see names like [Wernher von Kerman](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Wernher_von_Kerman) or [Gene Kerman](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Gene_Kerman) to remember the old Apollo and Gemini flights, but even near-future propulsions are implemented, although the game doesn't take itself too seriously.

The simulations are, as Mołot stated in his comment, not n-physics based, but work with [Sphere of Influence](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Sphere_of_influence). On top of that, the Kerbal System (the equivalent of the Solar System) is roughly 1/10 downscaled to the real solar system, but still with the same surface gravity. Overall, I would say the feeling is much the same, the orbital mechanics are the same, but with many differences in technology. I recommend it, if you want to learn the basics of orbital mechanics in a practical way.

Two points I need to add:

- The game is not easy. It is literally **rocket science**.
- If you don't like the simplifications made in the simulation, there are mods that overhaul the complete game. Real solar system, accurate planets and rocket engines with equivalents in the real world, even an [n-body simulation](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/162200-wip131-14x-151-principia%E2%80%94version-%E1%BC%90%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%82-released-2018-11-07%E2%80%94n-body-and-extended-body-gravitation-axial-tilt/). But, all these modifications make the game even more complicated and harder. The game on its own is very laggy, depending on the size of the simulated rocket, so modding it even further most likely won't make it any better.

And if you really want to take a look at planetary transfers, look for the [Hohmann Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit). That is the basic for every current interplanetary transfer

Comment: Wow that looks like serious stuff. I suppose I was hoping for something where I would say, "I'm in orbit on planet X and I'd like to be in orbit on planet Y - Please show me what fuel I need to carry, how long it will take me and the optimum trajectory" . Maybe that's a very big ask although I'll bet NASA has something like it as well as access to some big computers.

Comment: Note - there always been at least one "active" mod that changed Kerbol into our solar system, with correct distances and gravity. https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/177216-145-real-solar-system-v131-03-sep-2018/

Comment: @Mołot - Thanks that looks excellent. I'm planning to design my own solar system eventually (The planets will be closer together) but our one around Sol would make for excellent practice.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Kerbal is hard, but then, so is space travel. It doesn't have a simple learning curve, but it is really the best way to get intuition about how space travel really works.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK start with in-game, then switch to real one and see how harder it got. Then see how mod was done and mod it again to suit your needs. At least that's how I would go around it. On the other hand, I have KSP license anyway, bought for fun, so it doesn't *cost* me anything.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt realize you were asking for a hard science-based simulation. If you want to get into that, eg. delta-v requirements, you should look into the vis-viva equations. As i said, Hohmann transfer are the basics for interplanetary travel, thus assuming earth orbit as the low point in the orbit around the sun (periapsis) to the mars orbit as highes point in the orbit (apoapsis) for a earth-mars-transit. With that you can calculate the required delta-v, the speeds at apoapsis and periapsis. For a more detailed answer, you should add a "hard science" tag to your question.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK actually, [tag:science-based] requires answer to be scientifically sound. [tag:hard science] requires equations to be *in the answer* (and you probably do not want that if you ask for software that is doing it) or scientific papers proving answer is right to be linked, but software accompanying scientific papers is almost always without GUI or with very rudimentary one.

Comment: @ Mołot  - I'm confused now. I originally had 'science-based' and changed it.  I'm happy to change back.

Comment: I've added yet another note to my question to explain the current ''science-based" decision.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK There is a mod, [KSP Trajectory Optomization Tool](https://github.com/Arrowstar/ksptot/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks), which will do those calculations of "I'm in orbit on planet X and I'd like to be in orbit on planet Y - Please show me what fuel I need to carry, how long it will take me and the optimum trajectory."

Comment: You can also use the MechJeb mod as an autopilot for most straightforward orbital operations.  IMHO it's better to learn by doing, though.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the Apollo program *also* used the patched conics approximations (aka: "sphere of influence" model) for the lunar missions (given that slide rules have a rather lower performance spec than our gigaflop pocket computers) and this was perfectly sufficient.  Only to say that, while KSP is using approximate physics, it's exacty the same approximate physics that actually took us to the moon.

Comment: Also with regard to the patched conics: even N-body modeling isn't quite accurate.  That's why we have models such as [EGM96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) which model spherical harmonics in gravitational effects on Earth out to degree 360.  No matter what you do, there's always going to be some corner case you didn't plan for.  So might as well start with something easy (like patched conics) until you know enough to realize that you need to go to the next step.

Answer (score 10):

If you are content with flying around our solar system, I'd recommend the [NASA trajectory browser](https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php).

It lets you find realistic flight paths to many large and small objects in the solar system, for example starting from LEO and inserting into an orbit around Europa. The browser assumes standard rockettry, meaning flight plans using discrete burns with a defined delta-V to reach your destination. Sci-Fi stuff like constant acceleration rockets cannot be modelled. By playing with the maximum allowed delta_V you can simulate more powerful rockets.

You'd still need to calculate fuel loads manually ina spreadsheet or similar, using this form of the [rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) for each burn (start your calculation with the last burn, as the fuel for the last burn is part of the payload for the second to last etc.): $M_f=1- e^\frac{\Delta v}{v_e}$, with $M_f$ the propellant mass fraction and $v_e$ the exhaust velocity. $v_e$ is another parameter you can play with to get more science-fictional rockets.

How does this stack against your requirements?

- 3d view - no
- graphic representation - yes, simple/abstract
- travel times - yes
- fuel demand - only with the help of a spreadsheet
- fictional solar system - no

Comment: That looks good. Perhaps it might be used to check the correctness of my Kerbal journeys in our solar system. This will give me a feeling for other planetary systems.

Comment: "Sci-Fi stuff like constant acceleration rockets" are not that fictional. [Ion propulsion](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html) has low enough thrust that approximating burns as impulses no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

STK, https://www.agi.com/products/engineering-tools , is a tool used in creating many such visualizations by NASA, SpaceX, etc.

It's an engineering tool, so it's very realistic, but it might be a bit too much for a lay person.

Comment: Had a quick look. Seems worth pursuing.

Comment: They have a free version (limited, not sure if what you need is included), and also a full 1 month trial version. Also, I would suggest reaching out to them, they might be able to set you up with a longer trial or something. They are very friendly and accommodating.

Comment: I use STK professionally, and +1 this answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Universe Sandbox

https://store.steampowered.com/app/230290/Universe_Sandbox/

Very pretty, and as accurate as you are going to get on physics without a supercomputer doing detailed sums.

A little bit short on autosolving transfer orbits and such unfortunately.

Comment: The video looks very impressive https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/256655880/movie480.webm?t=1447377687

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe no one's mentioned Orbiter 2010!  Its similar to KSP, but without the building part, and with full-scale, n-body physics.  There is a mod for it called Interplanetary which allows you to input your location, your destination, and the maximum time you have to get there, and it will tell you how much dV you need and give you a trajectory.

Comment: That's very interesting indeed. I've just been following this up and a really good source for info is David Courtney's YouTube channel - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1bepNOil6LmbiQIYk6APaQ

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Kerbal Space Program as well, but here's a game I recommend you have a look at alongside KSP:

## [Rogue System](http://imagespaceinc.com/rogsys/)

I like this game because it tries to do something new and different. It brings a [DCS](https://www.digitalcombatsimulator.com/en/)-style level of simulation, but to a space game.

Yes, this means that it simulating something that doesn't exist, but the game's author has produced something that, to me, feels real.

Unlike KSP, with moveable cameras and views, in this game you only see the world through the eyes of your character.

It's still in early access, but in my view there's plenty in the game to keep you occupied.

I still haven't completed an orbital transfer in this game. In KSP I've sent manned missions to Duna (KSP's Mars), have landed multi-part bases on the Mun and Minmus, and remote probes to all corners of its solar system without problem.

In Rogue System I still have trouble turning on my engines.

Comment: "In Rogue System I still have trouble turning on my engines." Haha! Sounds like my abortive and abandoned efforts to play Tomb Raider  beyond the first obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

## Goddard Mission Analysis Tool

GMAT is free software from Goddard SFC that can do most of what you are asking to do, provided you already know a little about orbital mechanics. [You can find it here.](https://software.nasa.gov/software/GSC-17177-1)

It has Windows and Linux binaries, and can be run from a GUI or in script mode (you want the GUI, I would imagine). I use it occasionally at work for some geocentric orbits, but it is specifically designed for interplanetary missions.

The documentation is pretty good too, and there are several examples you can tweak to meet your needs. I used their Earth-Mars transfer example and got it running in about 5 minutes. Here are the screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The celestial bodies can be customized (planets added, removed, moved, increased in size, etc) so it should be good for a fictional solar system.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for required thrust, then take a look at some of the calculators created specifically for Kerbal Space Program, like this one: http://ksp.olex.biz/

Here's a comprehensive list:

https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Calculation_tools